# How to filter tokens based on a regex in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

For a ElasticSearch query we want to handle words (i.e. tokens only consisting of letters) and non-words differently. To do this we try to define two analyzers either returning the words or the non-words.

For example we have documents describing products for a hardware store:

```
{
    "name": "Torx drive T9",
    "category": "screws",
    "size": 2.5,
}
```

The user would then search for "Torx T9" and expect to find this document. Searching for T9 would be too generic and give too many non-relevant products. So we only want to search for the 'T9' term if we already found 'Torx'.

We try to create a query like this

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match: {
                    "name": {
                    "query": "Torx T9",
                    "analyzer": "words"
                 }
             },
            "should": {
                "match: {
                    "name": {
                    "query": "Torx T9",
                    "analyzer": "nonwords"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

The idea is that it would be simple to create token filters to do this. For example something like:

```
"settings": {
  "analysis": {
     "filter": {
        "words": {
           "type": "pattern",
           "pattern": "\\A\\p{L}*\\Z",
        },
        "nonwords": {
            "type": "pattern",
            "pattern": "\\P{L}",
        }
    }
}
```

But there doesn't seem to be a filter just matching on patterns. Instead we (ab)use the pattern_replace filter:

```
"settings": {
  "analysis": {
     "filter": {
        "words": {
           "type": "pattern_replace",
           "pattern": "\\A((?=.*\\P{L}).*)",
           "replacement": ""
        },
        "nonwords": {
            "type": "pattern_replace",
            "pattern": "\\A((?!.*\\P{L}).*)",
            "replacement": ""
        },
        "nonempty": {
            "type": "length",
            "min":1
        }
    }
}
```

This replaces the unwanted tokens with the empty token, which can then be removed by the nonempty filter. This seems to work, but the required patterns are more obscure.

Is there a better way to express this?

Comment: Can you also show one or two sample documents and illustrate what you'd like to match, respectively not match?

Comment: Maybe another idea would be to use a [shingle token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html) in order to index words together, so that `T9` would never be indexed alone, and thus never searchable by itself. Still looking for a way to shuffle tokens, so that together with the shingle token filter you could index: `torx drive`, `torx t9`, `drive t9`. I'm also looking towards the [phrase suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-phrase.html) which might provide a way to do this.

Comment: I like your proposed approach.  If the filter capabilities prove too unwieldy, just separate your words and nonwords into different fields as a part of your indexer (outside of ES).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [query-string-query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) with default_operator as "AND" for you requirement.

For example consider you are indexing two strings "Torx drive T9" and "Square drive T9".If you use the [whitespace tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html)  for indexing then the string will be analyzed as following tokens 

First Document :  `torx`, `drive` and `t9`.

Second Document :  `square`, `drive` and `t9`.

Then using query string query to match documents with default operator as AND will produce the expected result.

**Sample Mapping**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "whitespace": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "\\s+"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Sample Query**

```
{
   "query": {
    "query_string": {
       "default_field": "name",
       "query": "Torx T9",
       "default_operator": "AND"
        }
     }
 }
```

This query will yield result only when both `torx` and `t9` presents in the document.

Comment: What happens if you only request `t9`, do you also get results? I think that's exactly what @pmakholm wants to avoid.

Comment: Querying t9 will also produce results, but I think it is better to leave the choice to the user to query either `t9` or `torx t9`. In case if querying t9 should be striclty avoided then it can be done before querying elastic search either in client side or in java. If it should be done in elastic search then I hope it is better to use [shringles](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html) as you mentioned in comment.