# custom token filter for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

I want to implement a custom token filter like this:
single words are accepted if they match a specific (regex) pattern - adjacent words are concatenated if one ends in a letter and the other one begins with a digit (or vice versa)

This seems to map to:
step 1 - shingle - adjacent words joined together with a space
step 2 - if token matches pattern /pat1/, keep ... if token matches /pata patb/, replace the whitespace
step 3 - remove everything else.

Is there a way to achieve that?. I have seen [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742426/how-to-filter-tokens-based-on-a-regex-in-elasticsearch](https:////stackoverflow.com/questions/35742426/how-to-filter-tokens-based-on-a-regex-in-elasticsearch) but dont feel like converting a complex pattern into one with lookahead.

Comment: it would be great if you can add some samples as well

Answer (score 0):

the idea is to factor out potential order numbers from user input.
The data is assumed to be normalised, so an order number could be a regular isbn 978<10_more_digits> or something like "ME4713P". Users might input "ME 4713P" or 978-<10_digits_and_some_dashes> instead
Order numbers can be described as "contain both letters and digits, optional dashes" or "contain letters, a dash, more letters" or "contain digits, a dash, more digits"
BTW: sorry to use different email this time...